# Identical case condition

Tags: c#, vb.net, switch-statement, case-statement, vb.net-to-c#

I am converting some VB.NET code to C#, as I am more comfortable with it and it helps me in resolving issues faster. However, I came across this code which is NOT an error in VB.NET — but converting it to C# is generating a compiler error.

#### VB.NET Code

```vb
Select Case name
    Case "FSTF"
    .....
    Case "FSTF"
    .....
End Select
```

#### C# Converted Code

```
switch(name) {
    case "FSTF":
        ....;
        break;
    case "FSTF":
        ....;
        break;
}
```

And the error is:

> The Label 'case "FSTF":' already occurs in this switch statement.

What is the solution here — does it mean that in the VB.NET code, the second case statement was just a dummy — or was the first case a dummy?

Comment: What do you mean "was just dummy"?

Comment: if i have the following statements
int a;
a=1;
a=2;
then I would believe that the statement a=1 is dummy - as it's makes no sense to execute that statement; I know that without the information about the statements (function calls etc) - it would be difficult to tell ... so my question was which one is executed first, and which one next?

Comment: I have _never_ heard that term.

Comment: I know - my wording was wrong. I meant something like NOP

Comment: `dummy` from `dumb` meaning `unable to speak`. a `dummy` then became a mock of a human (also mannequin or puppet). Eventually anything that was a mock or placeholder of something became a dummy. `Lorem ipsum` is often called `dummy copy` or `dummy text`. And then eventually anything non-functional. In coding, this comes down to a NOOP as @user331225 said.

Comment: I think the real question here is:  In VB.NET, what happens when 2 Case sections have the same label?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

From the [documentation for Select...Case](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cy37t14y.aspx):

> If `testexpression` matches an `expressionlist` clause in more than one `Case` clause, only the statements following the first match run.

So here the second case is effectively redundant. Personally I prefer the C# approach of highlighting what was almost certainly an unnoticed programming error rather than the *deliberate* introduction of a duplicate case...

Comment: thanks for the link to the documentation! anyway that I can make vb.net generate compiler error for such things??

Comment: @user331225: Not that I'm aware of.

Comment: VB.Net allows one "Case" statement to accept a range of values (e.g. 6 to 10, or >9), and also allows case statements to use non-constant expressions.  While it might be helpful to have a warning when static analysis would show a particular case could never occur, the legitimacy of code should not depend upon a compiler's ability to analyze it.

Comment: @user331225 you can write you own analyzer which uses Roslyn compiler's API, though it will require a significant effort.

Answer (score 2):

I assume it was done this way to make VB.NET compatible with the [Visual Basic 6.0](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_Basic#Timeline) and older versions because that is the way they behaved. Had VB.NET reported a compilation error like C# then it would have been more difficult to port older Visual Basic code to VB.NET.

The odd thing about this is that VB.NET does not seem smart enough to eliminate the redundant case in the generated [CIL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Intermediate_Language) code. This leads to another peculiar difference between C# and VB.NET. That is, VB.NET does not change its strategy from a sequential lookup to a `Dictionary` lookup when targeting string types [like C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3366376/are-net-switch-statements-hashed-or-indexed/3366497#3366497). This means VB.NET's `Select` constructs using string types can be slower to execute than C#'s `switch` counterpart. The reason for this (credit given to [MarkJ](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15639/markj)) is because C# case statements can only contain constants whereas Visual Basic case statements can contain expressions.

Comment: C# `case` statements must be constant expressions, so the C# compiler can emit code that caches the `Dictionary` for later reuse. VB.Net `Case` statements can be expressions, so the VB compiler *can't* use that strategy in the general case.