# Switch statement with static fields

Tags: c#, .net, static, switch-statement

Suppose I have a bunch of static fields and I want to use them in switch:

```
public static string PID_1 = "12";
public static string PID_2 = "13";
public static string PID_3 = "14";

switch(pid)
{
    case PID_1:
        //Do something 1
        break;
    case PID_2:
        //Do something 2
        break;
    case PID_3:
        //Do something 3
        break;
    default:
        //Do something default
        break;
}
```

Since C# doesn't allow non-const statement inside switch. I want to understand what is the intention of this kind of design. How should I do something like above in c#?

Comment: will the values of PID_1 PID_2 etc change?

Comment: Mr.Mindor. No, but I want them to be static as well.

Comment: @Ashutosh All `const` values are effectively `static`.  They are not tied to an instance of the class.  You don't use `static` because it's redundant, not because it's not possible.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

It looks like those string values should simply be constant.

```
public const string PID_1 = "12";
public const string PID_2 = "13";
public const string PID_3 = "14";
```

If that's not an option (they are actually changed at runtime), then you can refactor that solution into a series of if/else if statements.

As to why the case statements need to be constant; by having them be constant it allows the statement to be much more heavily optimized.  It is actually more efficient than a series of if/else if statements (although not dramatically so if you don't have *lots* of conditional checks that take a long time).  It will generate the equivalent of a hash table with the case statement values as keys.  That approach couldn't be used if the values can change.

Comment: Ok. so why can't we use readonly fields? using const is not an option. Having a public static makes more sense for constant identifiers.. I can't use them anywhere I want and I just have one instance of it...

Comment: @Ashutosh You can't use readonly fields because the value isn't known until runtime; the `switch` statement will result in a table being generated at *compile time*, which is why the case statements all need to be compile time constants.  `"Having a public static makes more sense"`  If the values are actually constant I disagree.  Using a `const` value makes much more sense if the values are actually constant.  Note that all `const` values are effectively `static`.  They aren't tied to an instance of the object at all.

Comment: That's great when you are writing your own code, but when you are using something provided by another author/library in a switch/case statement, you can't just go change their implementation. I think this is one of those not-so-great trade-offs. I am having a hard time imagining why or how supporting this would or could be a problem.

Answer (score 29):

I know this is an old question but there is a way that wasnt covered in the other answers that doesnt involve changing the approach:

```
switch(pid)
{
   case var _ when pid == PID_1:
      //Do something 1
   break;
}
```

Comment: based on the question - this answer is correct!

Comment: This functionality is called 'case guards'.  
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/statements/selection-statements

Comment: Combined with the case guard is discards
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/fundamentals/functional/discards

Answer (score 5):

*... C# doesn't allow non-const statement inside switch...*

If you can't use:

```
public const string PID_1 = "12";
public const string PID_2 = "13";
public const string PID_3 = "14";
```

You can use a dictionary :)

```
....
public static string PID_1 = "12";
public static string PID_2 = "13";
public static string PID_3 = "14";



// Define other methods and classes here

void Main()
{
   var dict = new Dictionary<string, Action>
   {
    {PID_1, ()=>Console.WriteLine("one")},
    {PID_2, ()=>Console.WriteLine("two")},
    {PID_3, ()=>Console.WriteLine("three")},
   };
   var pid = PID_1;
   dict[pid](); 
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Case argument should be constant on compile-time.

Try to use `const` instead:

```
public const string PID_1 = "12";
public const string PID_2 = "13";
public const string PID_3 = "14";
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming there's a reason you didn't declare those variables as `const`. That said:

The `switch` statement is just shorthand for a bunch of `if / else if` statements. So if you can **guarantee** that `PID_1`, `PID_2`, and `PID_3` will *never* be equal, the above is equivalent to this:

```
if (pid == PID_1) {
    // Do something 1
}
else if (pid == PID_2) {
    // Do something 2
}
else if (pid == PID_3) {
    // Do something 3
}
else {
    // Do something default
}
```

Comment: Switching on strings could also be implemented as a dictionary (https://stackoverflow.com/a/3366497/616827).

Answer (score 1):

The canonical way to approach this -- if your static fields are not actually constants -- is to use a `Dictionary<Something, Action>`:

```
static Dictionary<string, Action> switchReplacement = 
    new Dictionary<string, Action>() {
        { PID_1, action1 }, 
        { PID_2, action2 }, 
        { PID_3, action3 }};

// ... Where action1, action2, and action3 are static methods with no arguments

// Later, instead of switch, you simply call
switchReplacement[pid].Invoke();
```

Answer (score 1):

Why you don't use enum ?
Enum keyword:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sbbt4032%28v=vs.80%29.aspx

In your case it can be easily handled over enum:

```
public enum MyPidType
{
  PID_1 = 12,
  PID_2 = 14,
  PID_3 = 18     
}
```

Comment: Because you can't assign a string to an enum