# C#, use reflection to get each case name in switch

Tags: c#, .net, reflection, switch-statement

Here's a contrived example of a string literal switch statement:

```
static string GetStuff(string key)
{
    switch (key)
    {
        case "thing1": return "oh no";
        case "thing2": return "oh yes";
        case "cat": return "in a hat";
        case "wocket": return "in my pocket";
        case "redFish": return "blue fish";
        case "oneFish": return "two fish";
        default: throw new NotImplementedException("The key '" + key + "'  does not exist, go ask your Dad");
    }
}
```

You get the idea.

What I'd love to do is print each of the literal strings for each of the cases via reflection.

I've not done enough with reflection to know how to do it intuitively. I'm honestly not sure if reflection can do this kind of thing at all.

Can it be done? If so, how?

Comment: Reflection is for looking at object information i.e. classes, properties, methods, etc. Code inside those things cannot be reflected. Look into the Visitor Pattern: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern

Comment: Unfortunately, the linked Q&A doesn't clarify here. It's still not clear what you mean by "initialized at compile time", and the answer given in that link specifically points out what I mentioned earlier, which is that if you have enough `case` labels (IIRC, the threshold is seven or more) the code just gets turned into a dictionary anyway. What are you trying to achieve here that you cannot with an actual dictionary?

Comment: I didn't know about that functionality. I was just looking for a const Dictionary at the time. The question though was weather I could get to these via Reflection or not. That's all I really needed to know. I know Dictionaries are the way to go and due to your advice I'll switch to that mechanism.

Comment: But what do you mean by "const Dictionary"? What, _specifically_, do you hope to gain? If you are concerned about runtime initialization overhead, then a `switch` statement doesn't solve that (large switches are implemented as run-time-initialized dictionaries!). If you just don't want any other code to be able to modify the dictionary, then see the [`ReadOnlyDictionary`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg712875(v=vs.110).aspx) class

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, you can't read IL (which is what you are looking for) with Reflection APIs.

The closest you can come is `MethodInfo.GetMethodBody` ([MethodBody class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.methodbody%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)) which will give you byte array with IL. To get implementation details of method you need library that reads IL like [cecil](https://www.openhub.net/p/cecil).

The `switch` for `string` is implemented using `if` or `Dictionary` based on number of choices - see [Are .Net switch statements hashed or indexed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3366376/are-net-switch-statements-hashed-or-indexed). So if reading IL take that into account.*

Note that you should use some other mechanisms to represent your data rather that trying to read it from compiled code. I.e. use dictionary to represent choices as suggested by [MikeH's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26747547/477420).

* <sub>info on `switch` implementation found by [Mad Sorcerer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3909293/mad-sorcerer).</sub>

Comment: This is what I was wondering. I agree the other method is a better way to store the information. But that's not what I was asking.

Comment: @colepanike Not the simplest task. Refer [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3366376/are-net-switch-statements-hashed-or-indexed) to see some details of IL `switch` implementation. I would use a `Dictionary` instead of parsing method's body.

Answer (score 2):

How about using a `Dictionary`

```
  Dictionary<string, string> dict = new Dictionary<string, string>();
  dict.Add("thing1", "oh no");
  dict.Add("thing2", "oh yes");
  //and on and on

  string GetStuff(string key)
  {
    if (dict.ContainsKey(key))
      return dict[key];
    else
      return null; //or throw exception
  }
```

For your menu:

```
 void addToMenu()
 {
   foreach (string key in dict.Keys)
   {
     //add "key" to menu
   }

 }
```

Comment: You could even use the shorter initalizer syntax: `new Dictionary<string, string> { { "thing1", "oh no" }, { "thing2", "oh yes" } }` and `TryGetValue`

Comment: The reason I'm not using a dictionary is the compile-time constraint. I chose this admittedly rather ugly syntax because a `Dictionary` can't be made at compile time.

Comment: @LucasTrzesniewski Very true.  I was going for clarity though.

Comment: @colepanike can you explain your compile time constraint?

Comment: @colepanike Just store your dictionary in a `static` field, and use the initializer syntax to init it.

Comment: @colepanike: what do you mean by "compile-time constraint"? How does your `switch` statement qualify as a "compile-time dictionary"? It's not like you can execute the code at compile-time. Also, are you aware that when `string` values are used for `case` labels in a `switch` statement, that the C# compiler will turn that into a run-time-initialized dictionary on your behalf (for `switch` statements with more than a few cases...otherwise the `switch` is implemented as a series of `if`/`else if`/`else` statements).

Comment: I agree, this is better and cleaner. But it's not what I'm asking. I wanted to know if reflection could get at these values. Thanks for your input though!